# Validar en que arreglo se encuentra un dato y que me sale el mensaje correspondiente

Tags: javascript, html, json, array, jquery-validate

Tengo ese codigo, quiero validar mediante el mensaje correspondiente, en qué arreglo se encuentra el dato ingresado, si esta autorizado o no.
Se ingresa el dato, y que me aparesca el mensaje en función a la ubicacion del dato en el arreglo, si esta autorizado o no. Y que me aparescan los otros datos tambien, así como esta en el codigo.

```
<script>

var usuariosAutorizados = [
{"nombre": "88888888", "agente": "MARCK IBRAIMOVICH", "user": "P67312"},
{"nombre": "77777777", "agente": "Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra", "user":"L97634"}
];

var usuariosNoAutorizados = [
{"nombre": "99999999", "agente": "Elon Muss Bodytech", "user": "S35678"},
{"nombre": "66666666", "agente": "Pablo Villanueva Melcocha", "user": "G15948"}
];

function ajax_get_json(usuarioIngresado) {

var resultado = document.getElementById("info");

if (usuarioIngresado.length === 0) {
resultado.innerHTML = "";
} else 
{
var datos = usuariosAutorizados;

var x = encontrarPersona(datos, usuarioIngresado);

// compruebas la longitud del array en lugar de true o false
var mensaje = (x.length > 0) ? 
    "<span class= 'autorizado'> Si está autorizado</span>" :
    "<span class= 'noautorizado'>No está autorizado</span>";
for (var numUsuarios = 0; numUsuarios < x.length; numUsuarios++)
{

  mensaje +=    "<span> <br>    Usuario: " + x[numUsuarios].user +"<br>" +
                                "Agente: " + x[numUsuarios].agente + "<br>" + 
                "</span>";
}
resultado.innerHTML = mensaje
}

}

function encontrarPersona(objetoJSON, usuario) {

var arreglo = [];

for (var i in objetoJSON) {
var persona = objetoJSON[i];
// sólo agregamos al array si el nombre coincide (y agregamos todo)
if (persona.nombre == usuario) arreglo.push(persona);
}
// devolvemos el array
return arreglo;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hola @Li0n11, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, añade más detalles a la pregunta: qué es lo que quieres hacer con el código, qué es lo que hace, qué errores recibes (si alguno)... Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Tengo ese codigo, quiero validar mediante el mensaje correspondiente, en qué arreglo se encuentra el dato ingresado, si esta autorizado o no

Comment: Dale al botón de [edit] y añade esa información (con algo más de detalle a ser posible) en la propia pregunta.

Comment: Si por favor edita la pregunta como dice @AlvaroMontoro porque se me dificulta mucho entender lo que quieres y así no te puedo ayudar

Comment: Ya está editada :)
Alguna idea?